# Increase download in google play

Tags: android

I want to optimize and increase the downloads of my created app. I recently discovered admob. But is it free? If not any other free alternatives? And can i use mobile advertising app with only one application submitted? Cause right now i have only one application published in google play. I saw appbrain sdk, but i think you must have more than one application created to promote your app cause it uses an sdk(meaning you will have to add something in your code). [Here](https://developers.appbrain.com/info/sdk) is the link. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other, perhaps better, ways than AdMob to increase traction. [This presentation at GoogleIO](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-62tRHLcHk) is one guy describing why his game became popular.

Answer (score 0):

Admob is not free if you want to advertise your own applications, you must first sign up for the service and set a monthly budget and range of advertising. In order to host ads in your mobile apps then yes, it's completely free you just need to download the SDK(I think v6 is the current version). And yes, you can create banner ads for only one app, if that's all you have to date. I am not familiar with appbrain sdk.